# IntersectionObserver + Scroll eventListener

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I'm using a mix of IntersectionObserver with a scroll eventListener.
Just to explain: The function is animating a CSS variable based on scroll position.

I order to prevent the browser to fire each time I scroll, even though I'm not near the element, I'm doing to do something like this :

```
if (entry.isIntersecting) {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', moduleAnimation, true);
} else {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', moduleAnimation, true);
}
```

I want the function moduleAnimation to listen to scroll only when the entry is intersecting. **It works fine**, except for the `removeEventListener`.

What did I do wrong? :)

Thanks a lot !

EDIT : Here's my complete feature:

```
    function stickyModule() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.full-module__img').forEach(function (module) {
        new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
            entries.forEach(entry => {

                let textOffset = module.parentElement.querySelector('.full-module__copy-wrapper').offsetTop;
                module.parentElement.parentElement.style.setProperty('--offsetWrapper', textOffset + "px");

                function moduleAnimation() {
                    console.log('scroll event');
                    let targetBrightness = 0.2;
                    let targetGrayscale = 1;
                    let targetContrast = 1.2;
                    let ImgDistFromTopDoc = Math.floor(module.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset);
                    let toScroll = (window.pageYOffset - ImgDistFromTopDoc) / (module.offsetHeight - textOffset);
                    let scrollGrayscale = toScroll * targetGrayscale;
                    let scrollBrightness = 1 - toScroll * (1 - targetBrightness);
                    let scrollConstrast = 1 + toScroll * (targetContrast - 1);
                    if (toScroll < 0) {
                        module.style.setProperty('--grayscale', "0")
                        module.style.setProperty('--brightness', "1")
                        module.style.setProperty('--contrast', "1")
                    } else if (toScroll < 1 && toScroll > 0) {
                        module.style.setProperty('--grayscale', scrollGrayscale.toFixed(2))
                        module.style.setProperty('--brightness', scrollBrightness.toFixed(2))
                        module.style.setProperty('--contrast', scrollConstrast.toFixed(2))
                    } else if (toScroll > 1) {
                        module.style.setProperty('--grayscale', targetGrayscale)
                        module.style.setProperty('--brightness', targetBrightness)
                        module.style.setProperty('--contrast', targetContrast);
                    }
                }
                window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY + 1);
                window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 1);

                if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                    window.addEventListener('scroll', moduleAnimation, true);
                    window.addEventListener('resize', moduleAnimation, true);
                    console.log('if');
                }
                else{
                    window.removeEventListener('scroll', moduleAnimation, true);
                    console.log('else');
                }
            });
        }).observe(module);
    })
} 
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', stickyModule);
```

I kinda new with JS sorry If my code seems crazy haha

Comment: Could you create an [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can experience and recreate the issue. This might be necessary to help you out as the code your provided show no appearant problem.

Comment: It looks like your code is "working" in that the event listener is added and removed when the element enters and leaves the viewport.  What are you expecting to have happen when the event listener is removed?

Comment: Never mind, I reproduced it.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the exact same function in `removeEventListener` that you used in `addEventListener`.  The same definition isn't enough.

In your example, you remake `moduleAnimation` for every entry every time the observer fires.  It looks like it's the same function, but it's a brand new one with the same name and same definition.  Instead, you can move the function declaration outside of the observer's callback.

```js
function stickyModule() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.full-module__img').forEach(function (module) {
        function moduleAnimation() {
            console.log('scroll event');
        }

        new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
            entries.forEach(entry => {
                console.log('entry', entry.isIntersecting)

                if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                    window.addEventListener('scroll', moduleAnimation, true);
                    console.log('if');
                } else {
                    window.removeEventListener('scroll', moduleAnimation, true);
                    console.log('else');
                }
                
            });
        }).observe(module);
    })
} 

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', stickyModule);
```

```css
body {
    height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" class="full-module__img">
```

Moving it out into the loop makes it still have scope with each `module`, but leaves the instance the same for each time the observer fires.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could actually do this with a single observer as well, instead of one per image, but that's a bit beyond what you're looking for.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Silly mistake ! Thanks a lot for your clear explanation !!